# MySQL count() with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

Many question has been asked with the same problem. But hear me out first.
I have two tables joining using `LEFT JOIN`, the first table is the user table and the second table is just a referential table division table

user table

```
 user_id |  name   |   division_id
 0       |  ABC    |     0
 1       |  DEF    |     1
 2       |  GHI    |     1
```

division table

```
id  |  name   | protect class
1   |  div_1  |      1
```

my original query

```
SELECT count(usr.user_id) 
FROM user as usr 
    LEFT JOIN division as dv 
        ON dv.id = usr.division_id
WHERE 
    dv.protect_class != '1'
```

but when I want to select user without a division

```
SELECT count(usr.user_id) 
    FROM m_users as usr 
        LEFT JOIN m_division as dv 
            ON dv.id = usr.division_id OR  usr.division_id = '0'
    WHERE 
         dv.protect_class != '1'
```

Things got a little weird, the user without division_id or equals to 0 get counted multiple times base on how many division entry a got.

I also tried adding distinct

```
SELECT distinct count(usr.user_id)
    FROM m_users as usr 
        LEFT JOIN m_division as dv 
            ON dv.id = usr.division_id OR usr.division_id = '0'
    WHERE 
        dv.protect_class != '1'
```

But still no luck for me.
And when I query this

```
SELECT distinct usr.*
    FROM m_users as usr 
        LEFT JOIN m_division as dv 
            ON dv.id = usr.division_id OR usr.division_id = '0'
    WHERE 
        dv.protect_class != '1'
```

And count it physically (by hand) the count is correct, then if I apply the count() function the count is wrong. So I just want to ask for advise on,
How can I count the entry without counting the duplicate in the my `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample  ..

Comment: does a simple sample data will be suffice?

Comment: yes a simple data set for check the behavior you obtain  for the severl queries

Comment: i dont get why you using this `OR  usr.division_id = '0'`

Comment: @A.Marwan  let's say it is required to what I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below - `count(distinct usr.user_id)`

```
SELECT count(distinct  usr.user_id)
    FROM m_users as usr 
        LEFT JOIN m_division as dv 
            ON dv.id = usr.division_id OR usr.division_id = '0'
    WHERE 
        dv.protect_class != '1'
```

Comment: Wow that was fast, thanks it works, I didn't know that distinct can be use as param in count()

Answer (score 0):

Join with 'OR' it cause multiple join when match condition

```
SELECT count(usr.user_id) 
    FROM m_users as usr 
    LEFT JOIN m_division as dv 
         ON dv.id = usr.division_id
    WHERE 
         dv.protect_class != '1'
         and (usr.division_id = '0' OR usr.division_id IS NULL)
```